# ADO.NET connection fails for a SSIS Execute SQL task once it is deployed to a SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ado.net, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on my first SSIS package that is pulling data from one on-premise SQL Server instance doing some transformations and writing it to a separate on-premise SQL Server instance.

While working with the package in my SSDT project all of my tasks run and work correctly.
Once I deploy the package to SQL Server the ADO.NET connection to the source database fails.

The package is deployed on the destination SQL Server instance.

There is a data flow task earlier in the package that uses an OLE DB connection which is successful and uses the same SQL Authentication username and password combination.

I get the error:

> Read Group Membership:Error: Failed to acquire connection "sourcedb.testtable". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

One thought is that I may need to configure an ADO.NET connection provider on the source database.

As this is my first foray into SSIS I expect the fix is trivial, I just can't get there.

Update with solution:
I resolved the issue by using an OLE DB connection rather than the ADO.NET. I didn't realize I could still sue the results from an OLE DB connected query to populate an ADO Enumerator.

Comment: Is it using SQL Login credentials (username and password) or Windows Authentication? When using Windows Authentication it's using your own account credentials on your development computer and trying to use the SSIS account's credentials when deployed.

Comment: I am using SQL Login credentials to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to use an OLE DB connection rather than an ADO.NET connection.
I had thought I needed an ADO.NET connection to populate my data and use it in a foreach as an ADO Enumerator.